# Confused by notation for normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

In my statistics course, we were taught that the normal distribution function can be expressed as $f(x; \mu, \sigma).$
However, I also sometimes see it as $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$
Are these the same? If so, why/how does the standard deviation "become" the variance?

Comment: Yes, they are the same (e.g., in terms of the density), just with different parameterization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard deviation did not "become" the variance. However, note that $\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma^2}$; thus if you know one of the two quantities then you know both. Therefore either measure of variability can be used to describe a normal distribution. In other words, the two notations mean the same thing.